# How to download the report as an excel in the PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, office365, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-api

How to download the report as an excel in the PowerBI. Currently, I have embedded the report in the SharePoint page using the PowerBi web part, would need to download the report using a download button.

I have used PowerBI API -
**POST [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/{reportId}/ExportTo](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/%7BreportId%7D/ExportTo)**

Response -
{
"error": {
"code": "InvalidRequest",
"message": "Report requested for export is not on dedicated capacity"
}
}

Comment: If I use the api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/{reportId}/ExportTo   getting the below error................{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "Report requested for export is not on dedicated capacity"
  }

Answer (score 0):

Export to excel file is supported only for Paginated reports.Error seems to be workspace is not on Capacity. Update your with workspace with any Premium Gen Capacity

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file#fileformat